# Determining when IE activex control has been repainted

Tags: internet-explorer, delegates, events, pinvoke, repaint

I was using spy++ and noticed that the IE control I have embedded in a windows form was periodically calling or sending WM_PAINT when it repaints itself.  I'm trying to figure out how in C# code I can perform a C# method every time this control sends WM_PAINT.  I know just enough pinvoke at this point to be dangerous.

Thanks in advance,

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need PInvoke to do this. The proper way is to use subclassing to handle specific Windows messages. Here's a link to do this:

[Handle Windows Messages with .Net](http://www2.sys-con.com/ITSG/virtualcd/Dotnet/archives/0112/hankins/index.html)

Comment: This is very useful info.  Great answer!